# Uninstalling ubuntu and installing windows

Tags: windows, bios

Recently built a computer and installed ubuntu 14.04 from USB. I struggle with using the interface, programs and terminal so I plan to put windows 7 ultimate iso onto a USB while in ubuntu. Then remove ubuntu and install windows 7. How do I go about doing this and what programs do I use? I have attempted to burn an iso file to a usb but it seems to corrupt itself, the usb might be the wrong file type for holding a windows 7 iso. I have attempted to do this before and I lost all of my files only for windows 7 to not install and so I came here to hopefully get some help. Since a moderator has closed the question that is unlikely.

Comment: Uninstalling ubuntu is trivial - simply install windows in the same disk partition.  As for installing windows from a USB device, I'd suggest asking at superuser.com.  I don't believe it's possible, but can't be 100% certain... somebody over there will know for sure, though.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a duplicate of the question indicated. The answers to that question are all about uninstalling Ubuntu from a dual boot system, which doesn't seem to be the case here.  Also the desire to use a USB device for the reinstall process is entirely new.

Comment: There is a way to somehow install from usb. From what I can tell you download the iso, burn the image onto a usb with a program (not sure which one works best with ubuntu) give it boot access somehow and install it. When you say uninstalling ubuntu is trivial I don't understand how to install to a disk partition...

This question is different from the duplicate as this computer has never had windows installed on it before.

Comment: Haha this is a quite nice example of easiness of Ubuntu installer in favor of Windows installer. If you can't use Ubuntu GUI and struggle with Windows installer, why do you think using Windows will eliminate your problem?

Comment: I mainly want to use windows for the games it supports and just installing programs is a lot simpler. The problem isn't the windows installer but getting the windows iso onto a usb to install it. None of the usual usb iso programs seem to work.

Comment: @user286430 - your windows 7 question is perhaps more relevant on superuser.com - please check there if your question hasnt already been asked.